# ssrs 2008 - Pass a parameter value to a variable in the dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have a variable in my dataset that is used to decide which query to run, something like:

```
DECLARE @Flag char(1);

BEGIN
 IF @Flag = 1
 (
    -- Run query1
 )
 ELSE
 (
   -- Run Query2
 )

 END
```

In the report I want have a parameter, either a drop down or checkbox (I'll figure out which), that passes a 1 or 0 to the @Flag variable in the dataset so the correct query will run.

I have tried adding a parameter to the report, set to boolean, with the name @Flag, hoping it will make the connection, but I am getting an error saying @Flag needs to be declared.  I have tried some other things but tracking it with SQL profiler shows no value getting there.  How do I get a value from a parameter to a dataset variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a text query embedded in an SSRS report, you shouldn't need to `DECLARE` a parameter you're referencing in that query - just remove that statement.

If you have a parameter called `Flag` **(note - no `@`)** you should just be able to use this in the report Dataset query by referencing it as `@Flag` without `DECLARE`.

Comment: Did this help you with your issue?